# separar el texto de una columna según múltiples delimitadores?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito separa este valor en un campo 'data/soft_base' en sus 3 partes:
 'data' - 'soft' - 'base'
¿Cuál sería el procedimiento?
estoy usando substring, charindex y len pero no puedo separar el campo del medio.

```
 select entrecalles, 
    CASE charindex('/',entrecalles) WHEN 0 THEN entrecalles
    ELSE LEFT(entrecalles,charindex('/', entrecalles)- 1) END as Almacen1,

    substring(entrecalles, charindex('/', entrecalles)+1,
    charindex('_',entrecalles,1)) as Almacen2,

    replace(substring(entrecalles, charindex('_',entrecalles,
    charindex('/',entrecalles)+1), len(entrecalles)),'_','') as Almacen3  from art (nolock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es este es el código necesario para la intermedia:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(entrecalles, LEN(entrecalles)-charindex('/', entrecalles)),charindex('_', entrecalles)-LEN(LEFT(entrecalles,charindex('/',entrecalles)))-1)
```

Quedaría

```
 select entrecalles, 
    CASE charindex('/',entrecalles) WHEN 0 THEN entrecalles
    ELSE LEFT(entrecalles,charindex('/', entrecalles)- 1) END as Almacen1,

    LEFT(RIGHT(entrecalles, LEN(entrecalles)-charindex('/', entrecalles)),charindex('_', entrecalles)-LEN(LEFT(entrecalles,charindex('/',entrecalles)))-1) as Almacen2,

    replace(substring(entrecalles, charindex('_',entrecalles,
    charindex('/',entrecalles)+1), len(entrecalles)),'_','') as Almacen3  from art (nolock)
```

Explicación: tomo de la derecha(right), todo menos la primera palabra y el "/".

Tomo de la izquierda(left)(de lo que me quedo en el paso anterior), pero para saber el punto en el que esta el "_" debo sumarle al *index* resultante las letras que le saque en el paso anterior.

```
LEFT(RIGHT(entrecalles, LEN(entrecalles)-charindex('/', entrecalles)),charindex('_', entrecalles)-LEN(LEFT(entrecalles,charindex('/',entrecalles)))-1)
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.